# Selecting data in Access: if duplicates exist, only selecting one of them

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, duplicates

How do I select all the records in a MS Access table and if the specified field has duplicates, to only select the field once.  I will explain in an example below.

If the field I need to fetch is the full name field and have it displayed in my web application, sometimes my Database has the full name shown more than once.  This is allowed for various purposes related to other fields in the table.  Therefore, the database could be like this:

- Smith, John
- Blow, Joe
- Bond, James
- Blow, Joe
- Bunny, Bugs
- Blow, Joe

Notice that Blow, Joe is in the database 3 times.  When I select them for alphabetical output, I want my output in the web application to be like this:

- Blow, Joe
- Bond, James
- Bunny, Bugs
- Smith, John

Only showing Blow, Joe once instead of 3 times.  What is the correct SQL query to do this?
Currently my query is "Select fullname from nametable order by fullname".
What should I add to the query to only show each record (if there are duplicates) once?  The query also cannot be affected by other fields in the database, meaning the query cannot source or use other fields as a filter because the other fields are only data without any unique values from each other.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` predicate.

In your case the correct syntax is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fullname FROM nametable ORDER BY fullname
```